# user didn't interact with the document first

Tags: javascript, audio

I'm getting an error called `Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first.`
Does anyone know how to fix this?

```
const audioCls = new Audio("/assets/audio/a4.mp3");
setInterval(() => {
  audioCls.play();
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clicking the document fixed the issue :)